# how does row and columns work in angular + Bootstrap

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to understand how angular calculates how the elements are rendered in the dom.
more specifically, how row and column work

I added some examples below with what i was expecting to see but i dont see what I am expecting in any case lol

[image: rows vs colums]

```
<p>this should be displayed one below the other one I would expect, but it displays one next to the other</p>
<button class="btn btn-success">Start game</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger">Stop</button>

<p>this should be displayed in two columns I would expect, but i see two rows </p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <p>hi</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <p>bye</p>
  </div>
</div>

<p>this should be displayed in two colums, i would expect, but it shows up as 2 rows </p>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <button class="btn btn-success">Start game</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Stop</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the outer container element a thinner width than 100%?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the grid system, your rows and columns must at some point be descendants of an element with the `.container` class.

[Latest 5.2 docs on container](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/containers/), but I think this applies all the way back to Bootstrap 3.